# Background color shrinks with window resize

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem. My page doesn't look like what i am expecting.

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
.width{width:980px;margin:0 auto;}
.header{width:100%;background-color:#ffffbb;}
.leftpanel{float:left;height:50px;}
.rightpanel{float:right;height:50px;}
.clear{clear:both;}
h2{font-size:32px;}
```

```html
 <!-- HEADER AREA -->
 <div class="header">
  <div class="width">
   <div class="leftpanel">
    <h2>This is first sentence</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="rightpanel">
    <h2>This is second sentence</h2>
   </div> 
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

On window minimize my header color is getting shrinks and not covering whole width of the content. How to fix it ? I tried to use max-width:980px; but that is collapsing the content when minimizing the browser. I want bottom scroll to cover the whole width without collapsing the content and background color to get fixed.

Comment: .width{width:980px;margin:0 auto;background-color:#ffffbb;} Is this desired behavior? https://jsfiddle.net/xnx9ccfs/

Comment: That i tried but it will not fix the problem actually. Bcoz in this case when window is maximized the width portion will come in center of the page and rest page remain default white background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're doing wrong. Basically, your header only extends to a width of 100%, that is 100% of the viewport. When you shrink your screen past 980px, as denoted by your .width element some of your content goes out of the viewport thereby extending outside of the header. You can do many things to fix this, a really quick fix would be to add a float to the header and set its minimum width to 100%. e.g.

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
.width{width:980px;margin:0 auto;}
.header{min-width:100%;float:left;background-color:#ffffbb;}
.leftpanel{float:left;height:50px;}
.rightpanel{float:right;height:50px;}
.clear{clear:both;}
h2{font-size:32px;}
```

```html
 <!-- HEADER AREA -->
 <div class="header">
  <div class="width">
   <div class="leftpanel">
    <h2>This is first sentence</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="rightpanel">
    <h2>This is second sentence</h2>
   </div> 
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Exactly , this is what i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, remember to select this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are giving fixed width to the elements .
Use the following Css and your problem will be solved:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
.width{width:100%;margin:0 auto;}
.header{width:100%;background-color:#ffffbb;}
.leftpanel{float:left;height:50%;}
.rightpanel{float:right;height:50%;}
.clear{clear:both;}
h2{font-size:32px;}
```

Also try reading why not to give fixed width and height, this would help you understand better

Comment: This case is of fluid design. I was not making a fluid design actually otherwise i will better use bootstrap.